# При выводе диалога PyQt5 выходит ошибка

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qinputdialog

При попытке вывести диалог, выводит ошибку:

> **TypeError**: getText(QWidget, str, str, echo: QLineEdit.EchoMode =
> QLineEdit.Normal, text: str = '', flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags,
> Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags(), inputMethodHints:
> Union[Qt.InputMethodHints, Qt.InputMethodHint] = Qt.ImhNone):
> **argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'**

UI: https://yadi.sk/d/2_YDsvmG6CAjAQ

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit,
    QInputDialog, QApplication)
import sys, os, pyautogui, time, random

class MainBtn():
    def maindo(self, countMess):
        time.sleep(5)
        countMess -= 1
        countNow = 0
        while countNow <= countMess:
            protect_first = str(random.randint(0, 1000000000))
            protect_second = str(random.randint(0, 1000000000))
            pyautogui.press("t")
            pyautogui.typewrite("[" +protect_first+ "] " +str(text)+ " [" +protect_second+ "]")
            pyautogui.press("enter")
            countNow += 1
            if countNow == 3:
                time.sleep(5)

    def start(self):
        os.system("msg %username% У вас пять секунд для возврата")
        MainBtn.maindo(self, changecount)

def changetext():
    text = QInputDialog.getText('Установка текста',
        'Установить текст на ')

def changecount():
    countMess = QInputDialog.getText('Установка количества',
        'Количество сообщений: ')

def btnVk_clicked():
    pass

def btnYt_clicked():
    pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = uic.loadUi("MadUI2.ui")

window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
window.setWindowTitle("MadMacro")
ico = QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")
app.setWindowIcon(ico)
window.move(0, 0)

window.btnChangeText.clicked.connect(changetext)
window.btnChangeCount.clicked.connect(changecount)
window.btnStart.clicked.connect(MainBtn.start)
window.btnQuit.clicked.connect(app.quit)
window.btnYt.clicked.connect(btnYt_clicked)
window.btnVk.clicked.connect(btnVk_clicked)

window.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста `MadUI2.ui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QInputDialog.getText(...)` - Создает диалоговое окно ввода текста 
и возвращает введенный текст и состояние нажатия кнопки ОК.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QInputDialog, QApplication)


def changetext():
#   text = QInputDialog.getText('Установка текста', 'Установить текст на ')
    text, status = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(window, 'Установка текста', 'Введите текст: ') # <-----
    print(f"text={text}, status={status}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()

    window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    window.setWindowTitle("MadMacro")
    ico = QtGui.QIcon("im.png")
    app.setWindowIcon(ico)
    window.move(110, 110)

    btnChangeText = QPushButton("btnChangeText", window)
    btnChangeText.move(50, 50)
    #window.btnChangeText.clicked.connect(changetext)
    btnChangeText.clicked.connect(changetext)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS. Но это не самое страшное с чем вы столкнулись. Впереди вас ждет замораживание графического интерфейса, т.к. вы и используете `time.sleep(5)` и цикл `while`. Но это уже другая история.